# avrdude - Set programmer's path

Tags: avr, linux, programmer, avrdude

I am trying to upload a hex file to my ATtiny85 with my AVR ISP MKII programmer. But `avrdude` says it cannot find my programmer. How can I find where my (USB) programmer is located (I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) and how can I implement this command: `avrdude -p t85 -c avrispmkII -e -U flash:w:src.hex` to set the path of where my programmer is? MANY THANKS!

Comment: 1) Unplug your programmer; 2) On the command line enter `sudo dmesg -c`; 3) Plug in your programmer; 4) On the command line enter `sudo dmesg -c` again and copy its output into your question.

Comment: Probably a permissions problem. Might need to make a udev rule to assign the ISP mkII to your user (by vid, pid). If it works as root, but not as user, this is almost certainly the problem.

Comment: This is pretty easy to solve once you know what to look for. Consider joining us in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering I can talk you through it.